# Accidentally changed files using sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I accidentally changed a couple of files of mine using a wrong `sed -i` command. I need them back. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you change them in a reversible way (e.g. inserting a line at the top)? If not, do you have backup copies?

Comment: Actually no I don't have a backup copy

Comment: And can you describe the sed command you used?

Comment: Yeah it was `sed -ni '/init()/p' *.c`

Comment: Ouch. Yeah, that is not reversible.

Comment: Yeah :( I keep on working on some files which I would like to keep versioned, like I would like to be able to revert back to a day back's work or things like that. Do you have an Idea what tool can help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86662/discussion-between-mdsingh-and-beta).

Answer (score 0):

CRAP, I googled it for a while, and since I am not using any journalling filesystem, Its really not possible. I should have used `sed -i~` for backup. Heads up guyz, though I believe anybody who comes here has already done what can't be averted.